# Find(ID) do mongo não retorna nada

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-csharp

Tenho uma coleção chamada usuários no mongo com aproximadamente 1000 valores. Acesso o mongo através do MongoDB .NET Driver, no momento tudo funciona normalmente. Mas nesses últimos dias eu estava querendo recuperar alguns documentos dessa coleção manualmente, e não queria ter que mexer no meu código para isso.

Executei:
`db.usuarios.find({})` 
Que me retornou uma grande quantidade de documentos(Provando que está funcionando..)

Mas ao executar:

`db.usuarios.find({"_id":"295092462215757825"})` não me retorna nada. até tentei:

`db.usuarios.find({"_id":295092462215757825})` e nada. como mostrado na imagem abaixo..

[image: Imagem do que mostra]
Código fonte do meu projeto no Github https://github.com/ZaynBot/ZaynBot

O ID é auto gerado pelo meu código, por isso não é um ObjectID mas sim um ulong.

O que poderia ser que resulta em nenhum valor? Tenho certeza que existe até por que consegui o valor através do MongoDB .NET Driver.

Comment: Esse find pelo id estava funcionando antes ou você ainda não tinha tentado fazê-lo?
Outra coisa: pode postar em (formato de código) uma amostra do retorno do teu findAll, que contenha um documento?

Comment: @PedroRamos o find funciona nos ids que aparece no findAll, ou pelo menos nos iniciais.. Dessa [forma?](https://hastebin.com/izokugurin.json)

Comment: @PedroRamos usei o Robo 3T e consegui ver todos os documentos, posso olhar um por um, mas quando vou usar o find não aparece, mesmo estando no Robo 3T.. Até Copiei o código que aparece no Robo 3T e não encontra no mongo...

Comment: @PedroRamos Obrigado, acho que achei o problema, no caso eu não estava convertendo o número para ulong, só colocando o número cru mesmo, após ter enviado uma amostra do findAll percebi e resolvi testar. Fui tentar com `db.usuarios.find({"_id":NumberLong("383711472221421589")})` ele agora está achando todos os documentos que eu peço. :D

Comment: Beleza, então. Fico feliz que tenha conseguido!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o Id é do tipo long, fiz da seguinte forma que me retornou o documento:

`db.usuarios.find(({"_id" : NumberLong("87604980344721408")})`

Tentando das seguintes formas retornava nada:

`db.usuarios.find(({"_id" : NumberLong(87604980344721408)})`

`db.usuarios.find(({"_id" : 87604980344721408)})`

`db.usuarios.find(87604980344721408)`

Fica a dica para quem estiver com problemas.